# Disable single-click file browser behavior

Tags: qt

Since recent Clementine update, behavior of Files tab has changed: folders and files now open on single click instead of double click.

I have not found setting for this in Clementine but since the file browser is provided by Qt (Qt4 in this case), I believe there should be a configurable global or user-specific default that would be inherited by all Qt applications.

Does anybody know where to find such file and what in particular to put inside?

(My system is Fedora 24 but I guess also other distro/platform suggestions could be shared here.)

Answer (score 3):

Opening file *kdeglobals* and adding this section helped:

```
[KDE]
SingleClick=false
```

This file is located under `~/.kde/share/config` on my Fedora.  (Some sources mention similar path with `.kde4`, so that might be the case for some systems.)

On Windows this [should be](https://community.kde.org/Windows/Fine-tuning) `%USERPROFILE%\.kde\share\config` (haven't tested it myself).

Thanks to @kishore96 on #clementine Freenode IRC channel!

Comment: Just in case somebody finds this after such a long time - one of my Qt apps suddenly started showing the "single click to open" behaviour (which I strongly dislike). I was able to fix it by setting `SingleClick=false` in `$HOME/.config/kdedefaults/kdeglobals`. Thanks for the pointer!